# Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle : Override Mailer

Tags: php, symfony, service, fosuserbundle, mailer

i come here because i have a problem with OVH and my symfony2 application, i can't send mail with SwiftMailer. It's rather problematic for FOSUserBundle to reset the password or activate my account after inscription. So i want to use the `MAIL` function implemented in PHP, i followed the documentation [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/emails.md) . So i created my class `MailerInterface.php`and the class `Mailer.php` because this class send the mail with the function `sendEmailMessage`

Here, you can see how i implemented the class :

```
<?php
      namespace MonApp\UserBundle\Mailer;

      use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

      interface MailerInterface
      {
           function sendConfirmationEmailMessage(UserInterface $user);

           function sendResettingEmailMessage(UserInterface $user);
      }
?>
```

And the `Mailer.php` :

```
<?php
      namespace MonApp\UserBundle\Mailer;

      use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
      use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
      use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
      use MonApp\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface;

      class Mailer implements MailerInterface
      {
          protected $mailerMonApp;
          protected $router;
          protected $templating;
          protected $parameters;

          public function __construct($mailerMonApp, RouterInterface $router, EngineInterface $templating, array $parameters) {
               $this->mailerMonApp = $mailerMonApp;
               $this->router = $router;
               $this->templating = $templating;
               $this->parameters = $parameters;
          }

          public function sendConfirmationEmailMessage(UserInterface $user) {
               The function...
          }

          public function sendResettingEmailMessage(UserInterface $user) {
               The function...
          }

          protected function sendEmailMessage($renderedTemplate, $fromEmail, $toEmail) {
              $renderedLines = explode("\n", trim($renderedTemplate));
              $subject = $renderedLines[0];
              $body = implode("\n", array_slice($renderedLines, 1));

              mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, 'noreply@nondedomaine.fr');
          }
     }
```

I added my class as service :

```
services:
     monapp.mailer:
          class: MonApp\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer
```

And changed the `config.yml` :

```
service:
    mailer: monapp.mailer
```

Here the `ERROR` in Dev env :

```
     Warning: Missing argument 1 for MonApp\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer::__construct(), called in /home/domaine/www/nomappli/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 831 and defined in /home/domaine/www/nomappli/src/MonApp/UserBundle/Mailer/Mailer.php line 29
```

My problem is : When i arrive on my reset password page, i write my pseudo and after validation of the form i got a white page. I think i call the `class and use` used in the tutorial so i don't understand my problem, maybe i forgot a use ?

Thanks

***EDIT***
Here the logs errors (Thanks to Michael & Yann for helped me) :

```
[2015-03-31 14:55:35] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_resetting_send_email" (parameters: "_controller": "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController::sendEmailAction", "_route": "fos_user_resetting_send_email") [] []
[2015-03-31 14:55:35] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2015-03-31 14:55:35] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template ""." at /home/nomappli/www/monapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 128 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException: Unable to find template \"\". at /home/nomappli/www/monapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php:128, Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template \"\". at /home/nomappli/www/monapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php:106, InvalidArgumentException: Template name \"\" is not valid (format is \"bundle:section:template.format.engine\"). at /home/nomappli/www/monapp/app/cache/prod/classes.php:742)"} []
[2015-03-31 14:55:35] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

Comment: A white page means an error to me... Can you provide any log ?

Comment: i edited my post to add the error. the error in DEV is   :    Warning: Missing argument 1 for MonApp\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer::__construct().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to copy-paste interface code. It should be at its place: in FOSUserBundle. You just need to implement this interface. It means that you need to create class in which you place `implements MailerInterface`.

You already have this class. Just replace `use MonApp\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface;` by `use FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface` and delete your copy of original interface.

**UPDATE**

As you updated your question I have updated my answer. Your current problem is about service configuration. You need to inject arguments for constructor in service definition:

```
services:
     monapp.mailer:
          class: MonApp\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer
          arguments:
              - @router
              - @templating
              - {from_email: {confirmation: %fos_user.registration.confirmation.from_email%, resetiing: %fos_user.resetting.email.from_email%}}
```

Also modify your constructor method: remove `$mailerMonApp` from arguments:

```
      public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, EngineInterface $templating, array $parameters) {
           $this->router = $router;
           $this->templating = $templating;
           $this->parameters = $parameters;
      }
```

Comment: Yes i forgot to inject the args but how can i know which args i need to send ? because in FOSUser the first arg is SwiftMailer. And i will not use SwiftMailer. Thanks

Comment: If you don't want any arguments just omit them from constructor.

Comment: I need to use $router, $templating and $parameters for the function "sendConfirmationEmailMessage" and "sendResettingEmailMessage" but i don't need $mailerMonApp. how can i found them ? i search how they are implemented on FOSUser but i doesn't find it.

Comment: in path/to/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/mailer.xml :
<service id="fos_user.mailer.default" class="FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer" public="false">
            <argument type="service" id="mailer" />
            <argument type="service" id="router" />
            <argument type="service" id="templating" />

Comment: Thanks guys, i updated my files, but now i got a 404 error after validation. i will post the log in my first post. Error look like : **request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_resetting_send_email" (parameters: "_controller": "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController::sendEmailAction", "_route": "fos_user_resetting_send_email") [] []**

Comment: No it's Error 500 sorry

Comment: This is not error. And I think that you should use more easy-to-study framework as your knowledge are very poor.

Comment: i found the solution ;) the documentation of FOS about this isn't really perfect... So thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the problem is quite clear, you are missing some references to your services.
You class is requiring (as contructor args) some parameters to be able to work. But your service definition don't provide any of these.
I think that you need to read a bit of [documentation about services in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).